# double nested form with devise and geocoder not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using complex nested form.
I have 3 models

Location

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :profiles
  geocoded_by :address
end
```

Profile

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

User (Devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

In my User/new view

```
= form_for @user, validate: true, url: user_registration_path, html: { class: 'new-user form-default' } do |f|
  = f.fields_for :profile do |p|
    = p.fields_for :location do |build|
      = build.text_field :address, :input_html =>{:id => 'geo-input-address', :value => current_user.city.name}
```

My problem is address field is not visible, why wouldn't that be rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a new user, the user does not yet have a profile or location. The `fields_for` iterate over the existing items.

Either you [override the devise controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers), and then in the `new` action you can write something like:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_profile
  @user.profile.build_location
end
```

So you are providing the `@user`-object with an empty profile and an empty location, so your user can fill it in.

A little easier, but also a little dirtier is to do is straight in the view (then you do not need to override the devise controllers).